# How can i Convert 110_181 to 11.0.181

Tags: python, regex

What is the easier way to convert 110_181 to 11.0.181?

I was able to convert 110_181 to 11.0.181 using following `str.replace` function.

```
.replace("_",".")
```

How can I convert 110.181 to 11.0.181?

Comment: Is it always three digits, underscore, three digits?

Comment: If you don't give more details, no one can help you.

Comment: Yes this is the format always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If string size and format will be same always, you can use slice operation and `str.join`:

```
>>> s = '110_181'
>>> '.'.join((s[:2], s[2], s[4:]))
'11.0.181'
```